# SQL Server 2008 get data from unified tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've a stored proc like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @code varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --code goes here
END
```

the proc reads data from one of n tables, based on `@code` passed. So I've a map linking codes with the actual table names, ex.

```
Code:"A" => dbo.JAN_SALES   
Code:"B"=> dbo.FEB_SALES
```

All tables have the same structure. I know how to get it done by using 'red' sql, wonder if there's more elegant/performant way of doing that with SQL Server 2008?

Edit 1 - Red sql is the sql, which gets built by concatenating its parts and executed by calling something like exec('select A. B, C from ' + @myTable).

Comment: If all the tables have the same structure, is it possible to have a single table with a "type" column (or "month" column, based on your table names)?

Comment: I can't change the DB structure.  The data is splitted by a number of physical tables due to a reason.

Comment: Just to be clear to all who may run into this red sql is dynamic sql correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be clear on what needs to be done, and there are no much more posibilities than creating the T-SQL code by 
1) adding IF blocks evaluating the @code parameter; or 
2) using Dynamic Sql ( dynamic sql = "red" ). Please note the dynamic sql is strongly discouraged for production environments.

*BTW* - On SQL Server 2008 you can use ***sp_executesql*** proprietary stored procedure. Microsoft's MSDN describes how it works [here](http://%22http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx%22).